# Django get method is yielding an error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm following a Django book (Django 1.0 Web Site Development). I'm finding that the book, although straight forward and easy to read, leaves out small details. However, this error that I'm getting, I have not been able to find a solution online. Thanks for any help.

Below, I added the Tag class to my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)



class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)



class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(Bookmark)
```

Then I attempt to run the following code at the python shell:

```
from bookmarks.models.import *
bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(id=1)
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(console)", line 1, in (module)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site\-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 132, in get
   return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 349, in get
   % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Bookmark matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means just what it says. `DoesNotExist` is raised by `QuerySet.get()` if there is no object in the database that would match the conditions given to the `QuerySet`. In this case it means there is no `Bookmark` object in the database with an ID equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add any data in the `Bookmark` table yet? [`DoesNotExist` is raised by get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) if there is no record corresponding to your query. i.e. if there is no record corresponding to `id=1`.

Comment: Easiest way to add it is by enabling the admin interface and adding it from the admin page

Comment: Thanks, but I added from the Pyhthon shell